# How can I write IIS Server URL rewrite for specific route of angular 6 application that return Server Error 404?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, angular6

I have hosted my angular 6 application on IIS server and there is a specific pattern that gets 404 error and the pattern is as follows:

http://localhost:4200/confirmatin/Id/token

that is

http://sandbox.app.com/confirmation/186d01b9-6984-4674-8a7f-fab03f0bd6da/CfDJ8McKuDKimzdIr7t2WefOlD1ZXQAD9C5q1aFKlmTCvVgfSvb8WdUCkGVUl5kvPvB2OdB1M2M4Ef6DMxX0b0b6cYZy7hxA%2B%2FpSyBuQbLFn0Mqw1T8mYkm6T66JCYw%2Bzp3qm0NBGuPlzo1%2BmhMePzNHb%2B1bR8rQS%2Bj8irqemy%2Bg5YJBTgyt1Cfch43zC5eneBaNu%2FNi8U5IwUT6gJLjznw%2Flutja48Jfe5DOkhlIvLWrGPNzbwZzLozqq3%2FjJIqFA88%2BQ%3D%3D

The token may contains any special characters such as /+-= etc.

If I removed the special character in the querystring, the pointer is passed to next phase with invalid token.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="angular routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html"  appendQueryString="true"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The angular route has following path set on routing-module.ts:

```
{path:'confirmation/:id/:token', component:ConfirmationComponent}
```

Could you please suggest what I am missing here?

Comment: As far as I know, 404 means page not found, I guess there are something wrong with your angular application route setting. I suggest you could post more details information about your angualr route.

Comment: @BrandoZhang  I have edited the question to accommodate the angular routing setting for the page.